# Phone number field validation not happening

Tags: django, django-forms

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Contact
    def clean_phone_no(self):
        cd=self.cleaned_data
        phone_no=cd.get('phone_no')   
        if(phone_no.isalnum()): 
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid phone number")
```

Hw should i validate a text field as a number field.

1.It shouldn't take symbols.

2.It shouldn't take alpha numeric characters

3.Should take only digits,limitation not required.

Googled for validation,not got the reuired thing.Can any one help me in doing this.

Comment: Use `RegexValidator` with `\d+` pattern. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#regexvalidator

Comment: I am new to django,Can i have a small sample related to this.

Comment: Or in your model definition, you could assign `IntegerField` to `phone_no`. That'd work too. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types

Comment: No models should not be altered,i should validate that any help please do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your case. Without any Regular expression and stuff.

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact

    def clean_phone_no(self):
        phone_no = self.cleaned_data.get('phone_no', None)
        try:
            int(phone_no)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            raise ValidationError('Please enter a valid phone number')
        return phone_no
```

I'm using simple Python `try...catch` and trying to cast the type of the input to Integer. Any string that cannot be turned to `int` will raise validation error.

Comment: `int()` will only accept integer numbers without any error. Nothing else.

Comment: validation is working fine,but validated data not saved in db,i used return phone_no @ last line

Comment: Yes, however the int function does take in negative numbers as well, allowing users to have phone numbers like `"-123456789"`. What you really want is `string.isdigit()`

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def clean_client_phone(self):
    client_phone = self.cleaned_data.get('client_phone', None)
    try:
        if long(client_phone) and not client_phone.isalpha():
            min_length = 10
            max_length = 13
            ph_length = str(client_phone)
            if len(ph_length) < min_length or len(ph_length) > max_length:
                raise ValidationError('Phone number length not valid')

    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        raise ValidationError('Please enter a valid phone number')
    return client_phone
```